# Angular 2: how do I detect attribute changes to input attributes on a Component?

Tags: angular

I've got an Angular 2 Controller which looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<div>The value is: {{ value }}</div>',
})
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  value: string;

  @Output
  valueChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.valueChange.subscribe(value => {
      console.log('new value:', value); // <-- does not get triggered
    });
  }
}
```

But when the value of `value` changes from a template binding:

```
<my-component [value]="someValue" /> <!-- valueChange not triggered! -->
```

The `valueChange` event isn't triggered so, even though the template correctly updates and shows the new value, the component doesn't know it's been changed.

How can I detect when input attributes on my controller are changed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my opinion, `Output` is for your component to emit event to others so they would update their view if necessary, it should only be used for changes made internally that need to be broadcast out (hence the name `Output`). Triggering an `Output` event on `Input` changes may cause unexpected behavior (as now that `valueChange` is triggered for all the changes both inside and outside, and not really an `Output` anymore).

In your case, if you want to do stuff when your `value` changes, you can make it a setter:

```
private _value: string;
get value(): string {
  return this._value;
}

@Input('value')
set value(val: string) {
  this._value = val;
  console.log('new value:', value); // <-- do your logic here!
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I've used setters for detecting when input variables have been modified. You have to use the `inputs` key in the `@Component` decorator instead of the `@Input` declaration to get this to work, like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<div>The value is: {{ value }}</div>',
  inputs: ['value']
})
class MyComponent {
  private _value: string;

  @Output
  valueChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  set value(value) {
    this._value = value;
    console.log('new value:', value);
    this.valueChange.emit(value);
  }

  get value(value) {
    return this._value;
  }
}
```

Also FYI, the class method is `ngOnInit` instead of `onInit`.

Comment: You can use the inputs property on the \@Component decorator *or* you can use the \@Input decorator on the set property. They both currently work, and the \@Input decorator seems to be the current preferred way

Comment: A get accessor should and cannot have a value, you may want to update your get method to `get value() {}`

I think your `@output` may also need to be updated to `@Output()`

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to work around the issue by implementing from `OnChanges`:

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
  for (let key in changes) {
    if (this[key + 'Change'])
      this[key + 'Change'].emit(changes[key].currentValue);
  }
}
```

Which will automatically trigger the `Change` event whenever Angular detects a change… but is there any way to do this natively?