# angular2 @input - change detection

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

Is there a way to listen for @Input change?

In following example, I would like to be informed whenever 'inputData' value is changed.

```
@Input() inputData: InputData;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yeah, you can use `OnChanges` lifecycle event:

```
@Input() inputData: InputData;

ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.inputData);
}
```

Read more about Angular's lifecycle events [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

Answer (score 21):

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';


export class Demo implements OnChanges {

 @Input() inputData: InputData;
 ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}) {

    if (changes['inputData'] && this.inputData) {

        //your logic work when input change
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use something like :

```
Input('value')
set value(val: string) {
  this._value = val;
  console.log('new value:', value); // <-- do your logic here!
}
```

more info available at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820076/angular-2-how-do-i-detect-attribute-changes-to-input-attributes-on-a-component)

you can also take a look at [this article](https://ngdev.space/angular-2-input-property-changes-detection-3ccbf7e366d2#.je3rga93t)

Answer (score 3):

You could listen to `OnChanges` component lifecycle event inside your component

```
ngOnChanges(model: SimpleChanges){
   console.log(model)
}
```